# SpEL reference instance variable of class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-el

I am using a custom method for my spring security pre authorize annotation and I need to pass a long list of perms in. I want to store that list externally because its used in a few places butI can't seem to figure out how to reference said list. It seems to always come through as null.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/example")
public class MyController  {

...constructor/other stuff
public List<String> perms_I_want_to_reference = Arrays.asList("super","long","list")

@PreAuthorizze("@securityService.MyCustomMethod(principal, *this where I want to reference perms*)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?>doSomethingTopSecret(){
}

}
```

I have tried # and making list static and using `T` but so far nothing is working.

Comment: Whay do you need to pass them? Can't you just access them from securityService.MyCustomMethod?

Comment: so lots of controllers use that service and it has no knowledge of who is calling it ..it is true I guess I could refactor to somehow know or receive feedback on who is calling. I got this working with making perms list static and using T but wondering if anyone knows if/how/whynot I can't do what I want above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to access your field from the annotation is via reflection. In order to do that Spring needs to have an access to the field of that class. I have not heard of a method to get a reference to the current class when the expression is being evaluated, but one way to do what you want is to reference a bean itself and access the field:

```
public List<String> perms_I_want_to_reference = Arrays.asList("super","long","list");

@PreAuthorizze("@securityService.MyCustomMethod(principal, @myController.perms_I_want_to_reference)")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?>doSomethingTopSecret(){ }
```

Comment: so I found I could use `T` with full package name and access static properties of the class but ended up with something like your solution where I use another bean just loaded with constants because I felt like it read the best. The fully qualified package and variable name was to verbose for me.